# H264/MP4 live stream from ffmpeg gets delayed

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, mp4, live-streaming, video-encoding

I’m transcoding a MJPEG stream to H264/MP4 using ffmpeg. As client I’m using VLC.

I use this command line:

```
ffmpeg \
  -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 \
  -f mjpeg \
  -i "http://127.0.0.1:4100/getMjpegStream=L" \
  -f mp4 \
  -vcodec libx264 \
  -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart \
  -tune zerolatency \
  -crf 30 \
  -preset ultrafast \
  -g 1 \
  -reset_timestamps 1 \
  -vsync 1 \
  -flags global_header \
  -r 15 \
  -listen 1 \
  -fflags flush_packets \
  -avioflags direct \
  -flush_packets 1 \
  *output_URL*
```

If I set the *output_URL* to this:

```
udp://127.0.0.1:5000?pkt_size=1316
```

it works just fine. I start ffmpeg, then after some time I start VLC with this URL `udp://@127.0.0.1:5000`, and it plays (almost) real time. The delay is 1-2 seconds, which is acceptable. And this delay is constant, it does not depend on when I start VLC. I can stop and reopen VLC and it keeps going realtime.

But I need this stream to also be viewed in browser (in a HTML5 video), so I normally use this for *output_URL*:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

In VLC I use this URL `http://127.0.0.1:5000` and it also works fine, but only if I start VLC immediately after I start ffmpeg. If there is a significant delay between the start of ffmpeg and the start of VLC, then that delay will be noticeable in the playback. Let’s say that I start ffmpeg at time T then after 10 seconds (at T+10) I start VLC. I have this behavior in VLC:

- It starts, and it displays the frame at time T and then the stream freezes
- After 10 seconds, the streaming resumes in VLC and it starts playing, but the image is 10 second behind ‘realtime’
- This delays is constant, it does not recover from it

Is there a way to solve this?

- Instruct ffmpeg to start transcoding only when the client connects?
- Instruct ffmpeg to not buffer transcoded stream until the client connects? (with current command line, it clearly buffers because when VLC starts at T+10, the first frame displayed is from time T)?

Thank you!

Comment: i don't believe this is possible purely with FFmpeg.  I've had success in doing this with a lightweight Node.js process, which executed FFmpeg as a child process and buffered the appropriate data at the header.

Comment: vlc's log messages might be useful.  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide may also be interesting. GL!